# I want to match my array value to a column value from a table in php

Tags: php, mysql, select

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include_once('conn.php');
$data2 = array();

$content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$data = json_decode($content);
$couplenumber = $data->contact_number;

$sql = "SELECT * from `users_table`  where `phone`  IN  '$couplenumber'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        array_push($data2, $row);
    }
    echo json_encode($data2);
} else {
    echo 0;
}

$conn->close();
```

`$couplenumber` is an array it has multiple contact numbers. I want to match my array value to the table column named the phone. The phone has a string value that means a single contact. How I can get data after match phone value to multiple contacts of `$couplenumber` value?

Comment: You could use `implode` to convert the array into a string.

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL. The way your code is written now, someone could easily steal, incorrectly change, or even delete your data.

Answer (score 0):

It will be better, if you show us your arrays content. But, if you have some things like one objects array and one array with ids only, let's try it:

```
//Arrays are like :
$tab1 = [3,4];
//Considering Object is a class which receive id in constrictor and has et getId method.
$obj1 = new Object(1);
$obj2 = new Object(2);
$items = [$obj1, $obj2];

$tab2 = [];
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $tab2[] = $item->getId();
}

$diff = array_merge(array_diff($tab1, $tab2), array_diff($tab2, $tab1));

// True there are same, false there differents.
var_dump( empty($diff) && (count($tab1) === count($tab2)) );
```